# Issue in calling mapstatetoprops

Tags: react-redux

I'm trying a sample with React and Redux. I could see the call goes to my reducer and returning. But the mapStateToProps inside the container is not called. Below is the code snippet.

```
Container
--------------
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {loadCaseTypes} from '../../actions/caseAction';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import CaseSearchComponent from './CaseSearchComponent';
import configureStore from '../../store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();
export class CaseSearchContainer extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadCaseTypes());
}

render() {
    return(<CaseSearchComponent/>);
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
alert('mapstatetoprops');
return {caseTypes: state.caseTypes}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return {
    getCaseTypes: dispatch(loadCaseTypes)
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) 
(CaseSearchContainer);

Reducer
-------
let cases = [];

export default function caseReducer(state = {}, action) {  
switch(action.type) {
  case constants.LOAD_CASES_SUCCESS:
  return state;
  case constants.LOAD_CASE_TYPES_SUCCESS:
  const newState = Object.assign({}, state, {caseTypes:action.caseTypes});
  alert(state.caseTypes)
  return newState;
default:
  return state;
}
}
```

alert inside reducer is called, but the call does not get into mapStateToProps inside the container. Am I missing something in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mapStateToProps` to **get** state from reducer. You'll have an access from you Component via `this.props.caseTypes`

Use `mapDispatchToProps` to **change** state in reducer. Accesseble via `this.props.getCaseTypes()` (Perhaps getCaseTypes is confusing here, better use setCaseTypes or changeCaseTypes)

General mock-up for Container

```
import....

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
      caseTypes: state.caseTypes,
   };
};

 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   return {
    setCaseTypes: () => dispatch(loadCaseTypes())
   };
}; 

class CaseSearchContainer extends React.Component {
....   
render() {
    return <CaseSearchComponent/>;
    }
};

const ConnecteContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) 
(CaseSearchContainer);
export default ConnectedContainer;
```

In reducer declare an initial state and keep it immutable:

```
const state = {
    caseTypes: 'some case types'
};
export default (state, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case SOME_ACTION:
      return (...state, caseTypes: 'new case types')
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried your way, but still the same issue. mapStateToProps is not called after the reducer changes the state. Also, when accessing the function inside mapDispatchToProps using this.props gives "Uncaught TypeError: this.props.setCaseTypes is not a function"